# Match until specific word...

Tags: regex

Cannot for the life of me figure this out...

I am parsing a recipe:

```
Steak and Eggs
Serves 1
150g potatoes, diced
2 tsp olive oil
½ white onion, peeled and chopped
Salt and pepper
200g sirloin steak or rump steak, trimmed of fat
2 large eggs
Reduced carb meal
Family friendly
```

This is my the first part of the reg ex which matches the title and Serving number:

```
(\D*\n*)(?:\nServes )(\d\n)
```

I want to stop matching when it hits the categories at the end. I've worked out these may contain 'Reduced' 'Family' 'Quick' etc.

I have then tried to do this as so:

```
/(\D*\n*)(?:\nServes )(\d\n)((.*\n)*)(?:Carb|Reduced|Quick|Family)/
```

However, if there are two tags, as in the example, 'Reduced Carb meal' will be included as the Reg Ex continues until the 'Family' line.

Any help would be appreciated as I've been on this for 2 hours!

Comment: Try [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1VpLC/1) by making the `(.*\n)*` lazy and use a lookahead for not including the stop word.

Comment: @bobblebubble That works but I would suggest adding word boundaries for the words in the lookahead to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: Also the lookahead in my demo is not necessary as a capturing group is used already. However I like the idea of @PoulBak much more because it does not require the recipe to end with the words ([it even matches if none is present](https://regex101.com/r/D1VpLC/3)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change your non capturing group to a negative lookahead, like this:

```
/(\D*\n*)(?:\nServes )(\d\n)(.*(?:\n(?!Carb|Reduced|Quick|Family).*)*)/
```

Edited according to @bobble bubble's suggestion, give him the credit!

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble and Poul.